# Inequality involving matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I want to prove (or to find a counterexample) for the next inequality

$$c_1 \leq c_2$$
where the relations among the scalar constants are
$$x^T(A+A^T)x \leq c_2x^Tx$$
$$x^T(A^TA)x \geq c_1^2x^Tx$$
I know that $x^T(A+A^T)x>0 \implies x^TAx>0$

EDIT

You were right. The second inequality was wrong written, otherwise it does not make sense. Also you were right about the factorization of A, so I have dropped that part.

Comment: That $A$ is non-singular does not imply that it can be written as $P^TDP$ (or $P^{-1}DP$) with a diagonal $D$. Consider for example $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: @Mårten: But that $A$ is singular?

Comment: @joriki: No, neither all singular, nor all non-singular matrices are automatically diagonalisable.

Comment: @Mårten: I don't understand. I didn't write anything about what sort of matrices are diagonalisable. I merely pointed out that the matrix you seemed to be offering as a counterexample for a claim about non-singular matrices was in fact not non-singular.

Comment: @joriki: Sorry, my mistake. It should have ones on the diagonal.

Comment: @noether First, please get rid of the "$+A^T$", since it adds nothing, $x^TA^Tx=x^T(A^T)^T(x^T)^T=x^TAx$, so also  $x^T(A+A^T)x>0\Rightarrow x^T A x>0$ is trivial, since $x^T(A+A^T)x=2x^TAx$. Then, after your change to the $c_1$-inequality, you have $c^2_1=\lambda_{\min}(A^TA)=\sigma_{\min}(A)$. So, it doesn't change much, since $\lambda_{\max}(A)$ can still be negative. Things could only change, if you required $A$ to be positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^T x$ is non-negative, taking it to the other side of your inequalities doesn't change their direction. Thus you have lower bounds on both $c_2$ and $|c_1|$. In order to derive an inequality between them, you'd need an upper bound on one and a lower bound on the other.

To construct a simple counterexample, just choose $A$ to be the identity and $x$ an arbitrary unit vector; then the given inequalities are $2\le c_2$ and $1\le c_1^2$, and they're satisfied by $c_1=3$ and $c_2=2$ with $c_1\not\le c_2$.

Comment: You are right. The second inequality was wrong written. My misstake

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably mean the infimum of those $c_1$ and $c_2$ that fulfill your inequalities (i.e. the *least* upper bound, not just any upper bound). Otherwise the whole problem does not make any sense, as you can see in joriki's answer. So, what you probably mean is:
\begin{align}
c_2 &= \sup_{x\not=0}\frac{x^T(A+A^T)x}{x^Tx}\\
c_1 &= \left(\sup_{x\not=0}\frac{x^T(A^TA)x}{x^Tx}\right)^{1/2}
\end{align}
In the equation for $c_2$, adding the matrix transpose is pointless, since $x^TA^Tx=x^TAx$. So you can just as well write
$$c_2 = 2\sup_{x\not=0}\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}.$$
Now, on the right you have (two times) the Rayleigh quotient, and taking the supremum of that gives you (two times) the maximum eigenvalue $\lambda_{\max}$ of $A$.

In the equation for $c_1$, you have the spectral norm on the right, which is the same as the largest singular value $\sigma_{\max}$ of $A$. So what you want to prove or disprove is effectively the following:

> For all square matrices $A$ it holds that: $\sigma_{\max}(A) \leq 2 \lambda_{\max}(A).$

Obviously, this cannot hold for matrices with only negative eigenvalues. Just take $A=-I$, and you have a counterexample, since $\sigma_{\max}=1$ and  $\lambda_{\max}=-1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wrote down the second inequality wrong, now it is fixed. So sorry for the inconvenience :(

Answer (score 0):

First not that you do not need $A$ be singular to do the factorization $A=P^{-1}DP$.
Second even if $A$ is nonsingular, there is no guarenty that $D$ becomes diagonal.
Third, even if all these variables were scalers, no conclusion could be made for the inequalities.